# Change the value that is being set in variable's willSet block

Tags: swift

I'm trying to sort the array that is being set before setting it but the argument of `willSet` is immutable and `sort` mutates the value. How can I overcome this limit?

```
var files:[File]! = [File]() {
    willSet(newFiles) {
        newFiles.sort { (a:File, b:File) -> Bool in
            return a.created_at > b.created_at
        }
    }
}
```

To put this question out of my own project context, I made this gist:

```
class Person {
    var name:String!
    var age:Int!

    init(name:String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

let scott = Person(name: "Scott", age: 28)
let will = Person(name: "Will", age: 27)
let john = Person(name: "John", age: 32)
let noah = Person(name: "Noah", age: 15)

var sample = [scott,will,john,noah]



var people:[Person] = [Person]() {
    willSet(newPeople) {
        newPeople.sort({ (a:Person, b:Person) -> Bool in
            return a.age > b.age
        })

    }
}

people = sample

people[0]
```

I get the error stating that `newPeople` is not mutable and `sort` is trying to mutate it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not possible to mutate the value inside `willSet`. If you implement a `willSet` observer, it is passed the new property value as a constant parameter.

---

What about modifying it to use `didSet`?

```
var people:[Person] = [Person]()
{
    didSet
    {
        people.sort({ (a:Person, b:Person) -> Bool in
            return a.age > b.age
        })
    }
}
```

`willSet` is called just before the value is stored.
`didSet` is called immediately after the new value is stored.

You can read more about property observers here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

You can also write a custom getter and setter like below. But `didSet` seems more convenient.

```
var _people = [Person]()

var people: [Person] {
    get {
        return _people
    }
    set(newPeople) {
        _people = newPeople.sorted({ (a:Person, b:Person) -> Bool in
            return a.age > b.age
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: modifying in `didSet` is not what I'm looking for. I know that's possible

Comment: is it absolutely required to change it in willSet? Can you tell me why?

Comment: Oh now I see your updated answer. computed property can work. Instead of `sort` if you use `sorted` you will not need to use a secondary assignment

Comment: yes of course. the accepted answer will not work without sorted.

Comment: Is it defined behavior that the `didSet` solution does not infinitely recurse?

Comment: didSet is not recursive at all in Swift4.  In Swift5, it's not recursive if called against 'self' like here, but if you instead had a variable that also pointed to the same instance as 'self', and set the property on that variable instead, it *would* re-call 'didSet'.  In other words, Swift5 is only non-recursive when setting directly against self from within didSet. It's now recursive when set any other way.

Comment: thanks apple... why you not let me extract that in to a method :-D

As a side note:

If you extract the sort mechanism into a method it is not breaking the recursiveness...

Comment: @ErikMueller What you want (custom attributes that allow you to apply your own logic, abstracted away) was implemented in Swift 5.1 via property wrappers (see: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617 , section Property Wrappers).

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to change value types (including arrays) before they are set inside of `willSet`. You will need to instead use a computed property and backing storage like so:

```
var _people = [Person]()

var people: [Person] {
    get {
        return _people
    }
    set(newPeople) {
        _people = newPeople.sorted { $0.age > $1.age }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rakeshbs's answer is also reasonable. If you want to see the property before and after it's assigned, if you want to reject attempts to set certain values, or if you want to implement checks to avoid re-sorting when the arrays are the same, use mine. Otherwise, his solution is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for people who like abstracting away behavior like this *(especially those who are used to features like C#'s custom attributes)* is to use a [Property Wrapper](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617), [available since Swift 5.1](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md) (Xcode 11.0).

First, create a new property wrapper struct that can sort `Comparable` elements:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct Sorting<V : MutableCollection & RandomAccessCollection>
    where V.Element : Comparable
{
    var value: V
    
    public init(wrappedValue: V) {
        value = wrappedValue
        value.sort()
    }
    
    public var wrappedValue: V {
        get { value }
        set {
            value = newValue
            value.sort()
        }
    }
}
```

and then assuming you implement `Comparable`-conformance for `Person`:

```swift
extension Person : Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        lhs.age < lhs.age
    }
    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        lhs.age == lhs.age
    }
}
```

you can declare your property like this and it will be auto-sorted on `init` or set:

```swift
struct SomeStructOrClass
{
    @Sorting var people: [Person]
}


// … (given `someStructOrClass` is an instance of `SomeStructOrClass`)

someStructOrClass.people = sample

let oldestPerson = someStructOrClass.people.last
```

*Caveat: Property wrappers are not allowed (as of time of writing, Swift 5.7.1) in top-level code— they need to be applied to a property var in a struct, class, or enum.*

---

To more literally follow your sample code, you could easily also create a `ReverseSorting` property wrapper:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct ReverseSorting<V : MutableCollection & RandomAccessCollection & BidirectionalCollection>
    where V.Element : Comparable
{
    // Implementation is almost the same, except you'll want to also call `value.reverse()`:
    //   value = …
    //   value.sort()
    //   value.reverse()
}
```

and then the oldest person will be at the first element:

```swift
// …
    @Sorting var people: [Person]
// …

someStructOrClass.people = sample
let oldestPerson = someStructOrClass.people[0]
```

---

And even more directly, if your use-case demands using a comparison closure via `sort(by:…)` instead of implementing `Comparable` conformance, you can do that to:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct SortingBy<V : MutableCollection & RandomAccessCollection>
{
    var value: V
    
    private var _areInIncreasingOrder: (V.Element, V.Element) -> Bool
    
    public init(wrappedValue: V, by areInIncreasingOrder: @escaping (V.Element, V.Element) -> Bool) {
        _areInIncreasingOrder = areInIncreasingOrder
        
        value = wrappedValue
        value.sort(by: _areInIncreasingOrder)
    }
    
    public var wrappedValue: V {
        get { value }
        set {
            value = newValue
            value.sort(by: _areInIncreasingOrder)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// …
    @SortingBy(by: { a, b in a.age > b.age }) var people: [Person] = []
// …

someStructOrClass.people = sample
let oldestPerson = someStructOrClass.people[0]
```

*Caveat: The way `SortingBy`'s `init` currently works, you'll need to specify an initial value (`[]`).  You can remove this requirement with an additional `init` (see [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617)), but that approach is much less complicated when your property wrapper works on a concrete type (e.g. if you wrote a non-generic `PersonArraySortingBy` property wrapper), as opposed to a generic-on-protocols property wrapper.*