# Swift appropriate handling of stored property (willSet/didSet)

Tags: swift

For stored property we use observers such as **willSet** and **didSet**.
This allows us to track any change, that is done to that property.

First willSet is called, **property changed**, and then didSet is called.

Question is: How to handle input for property?

All examples i saw, do it in **didSet**, that means property **first changed**, then checked by **if/else** in **didSet** and changed **again** if does match criteria.

```
var life: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if life >= 1000 {
            life = 999
        }
    }
}
```

Cannot we just check input in **willSet** for criteria and change it if match(without double changing)? If yes, could you please provide a very simple example.

Or the only way is to use **didSet**?

**Edit:** It looks like people do not understand what i am trying to ask.

1)I want to use only stored property

2)I want to know - can i change property in willSet **without using didSet**, as i already indicated. The links you provide cover the solution with didSet, that i already know.

If yes - then provide example, if not, then i already know how.

Comment: Use a computed property and it's setter to do this

Comment: I know that i can use computed property, but that is not the case. I am talking about stored one. With logic - possible/how or not possible. Thanks for attention.

Comment: Thanks for answer Martin R. It means i cannot change value. That is all i need.

Answer (score 0):

**didSet called after setting a new value.
willSet called before setting the new value**

```
struct animal{
var name: String
}

var dog:animal?{
didSet{
print("called setting a new value")
if var newName = person?.name?{
print("new name is\(newName)")
}
}
willSet(myNewValue){
if let myNewName = myNewValue.name?{
print("new name is\(myNewName)")
}
}
}
```

Comment: I already indicated that. Please read question carefully. That is not what i am asking.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810380/change-the-value-that-is-being-set-in-variables-willset-block?noredirect=1&lq=1