# Why can't I remove elements from an Array in its willSet event?

Tags: arrays, swift, value-type, didset, property-observer

The logic is to clear an Array when it has a specified amount of elements. I could put the check outside of the Array but I was trying to see what if do it in Array's willSet event. The result is elements in Array stay still.

Here is the code

```
var MyArr=[String]() {
   willSet{
        print("now count is:\(MyArr.count)")
        if MyArr.count>2 {
            print("now remove all!")
            MyArr.removeAll()
        }
    }
}

MyArr.append("hello")
MyArr.append(",world")
MyArr.append("!")
MyArr.append("too much.")

print("The conent is \(MyArr)")
```

MyArr was expected to have only one elements while actual result was four.

Comment: The value that gets passed in to `willSet` is a copy, modifying it won't affect the property value for value types.  You would have to use `didSet`

Comment: thanks dan....you mean that didSet has a reference value?

Comment: This is a good answer to the question of modifying a variable in it’s `willSet` method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27810480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing [the Language Guide - Properties - Property Observers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### Property Observers
>
> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value.
>
> ...
>
> You have the option to define either or both of these observers on a
>   property:
>
> - `willSet` is called **just before the value is stored**.
> - `didSet` is called **immediately after the new value is stored**.

As you are experimenting with the `willSet` property observer, any mutation of the property you are observing within the `willSet` block *precedes* the actual storing of the `newValue` which follows immediately after the `willSet` block. This means you are essentially attempting to mutate "the old copy" of `myArr` prior to it being replaced with its new value.

Arguably this could be discussed as something illegal, as any mutation of `myArr` should lead to the invocation of any property observers, thus mutation of a property within a property observer (mutation of *the reference* for reference types or *the value* for value types) could arguably lead to recursive calls to the property observer. This is not the case, however, and for the `willSet` case, specifically, instead a warning is emitted, as pointed out in [@vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482385/4573247). The fact that mutation of the property itself within a property observer will not trigger property observers is not really well-documented, but an example in [the Language Guide - Properties - Type Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID264) points it out [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### Querying and Setting Type Properties
>
> ...
>
> The `currentLevel` property has a `didSet` property observer to check
>   the value of `currentLevel` whenever it is set. ...
>
> **NOTE**
>
> In the first of these two checks, the `didSet` observer sets
>   `currentLevel` to a different value. **This does not, however, cause
>   the observer to be called again.**

This is also a special case we can somewhat expect, as e.g. `didSet` is an excellent place to incorporate e.g. bounds checks that clamps a given property value to some bounds; i.e., over-writing the new value by a bounded one in case the former is out of bounds.

Now, if you change to mutate the property to *after* the new value has been stored, the mutation will take affect and, as covered above, not trigger any additional calls to the property observers. Applied to your example:

```
var myArr = [String]() {
    didSet {
        print("now count is: \(myArr.count)")
        if myArr.count > 2 {
            print("now remove all!")
            myArr.removeAll()
        }
    }
}

myArr.append("hello")
myArr.append(",world")
myArr.append("!")
myArr.append("too much.")

print("The content is \(myArr)") // The content is ["too much."]
```

Answer (score 3):

The behavior has nothing to do with value type / reference type

Please note the warning

> Attempting to store to property 'MyArr' within its own willSet, which is about to be overwritten by the new value

which means that modifying the object in `willSet` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

aAlan's comment on `didSet` vs `willSet` is interesting. I tried the same code but with `didSet` and it **did** remove the elements from the array which seemed odd initially. I think it's by design. My reasoning is:

- if you actually did get a reference to the actual item itself inside `willSet` and made changes then everything would get overwritten. It makes all your changes nullified. Because you're doing this **before** you even read what's about to happen. Also (repeating what dfri has said) if you set it again inside `willSet` well then you're going to trigger the property observer **again** and again and will create a feedback loop which will crash the compiler, hence the compiler behind the scene <s>creates a copy avoiding all this...</s> will just suppress this mutation ie it won't allow it. It won't create a copy...simply put it would just ignore it. It does that by throwing a vague (because it doesn't really tell you that it will ignore the changes) warning:

[image]

- same is not true with `didSet`. You wait...read the value and then make your decision. The value of the property is known to you.

Comment: I was thinking about it in the same way as yours. But what about change of value triggers willSet/didSet again of the Array, which results into a infinite event loop?

Comment: @AlanHoo The statement about a recursive call (when modifying a property inside its property observer) in Honey's answer above is not true, as explained in my answer. _Arguably_, if this was the case, we could run into recursion, but it's not the case. Repeating the quoted part of the doc. in my answer:  _This [modifying a property within its property observer] does not, however, cause the observer to be called again._. The compiler does not create a copy behind the scenes to avoid this, the language is just designed such that observers do not get invoked for mutation within an observer.

Comment: @dfri thank you for the correction. I've made an edit. I feel like removing my answer, but I've decided to keep it since it's somewhat shorter/simpler than yours