# How can I use willSet to update or correct some value in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want use willSet to control a condition, and make necessary job for setting right value, but willSet did not help to make condition happen! The value still gets bigger than 5, what am I doing wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var value: Int = Int() {
        
        willSet(newValue) {
            
            if newValue > 5 {
                
                value = 5
            }
            
        }
  
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(value.description)
            .padding()
        
        Button("random update") { value = Int.random(in: 0...10) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the value that is being set in variable's willSet block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27810380/8697793)

Comment: Will set means it will set. So after you set a new value it still sets a new value after execution of the closure

Comment: thanks both, my all point is not letting even set the wrong value at first place, I could make this job happen in Button area, but I was so interested to solve this issue with willSet or didSet

Comment: @LeoDabus: can we use some code to defuse didSet from willSet? I mean some code that makes didSet not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `didSet` instead

```
struct Foo {
    var value: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if value > 5 {
                value = 5
            }
        }
    }
}

var foo = Foo()
foo.value = 6
print(foo.value) // 5
```

EDIT:

To illustrate that `value` will be set to 5 before observed as `6`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var value: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("setting value to \(value)")
            
            if value > 5 {
                value = 5
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(valueAsText)
                .padding()
            Button("Set value to >5") { value = 6 }
        }
    }
    
    private var valueAsText: String {
        print("value: \(value)")
        
        return "\(value)"
    }
}

struct MySwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MySwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

where tapping the button will output the following:

```
value: 0
setting value to 6
setting value to 5
value: 5
```

Comment: willSet is called just before the value is stored.
didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored. I do not want even store Wrong value at first place. that is why I attacked the issue with willSet

Comment: The issue is setting a value within its willSet will never override the setter, because the setter will always come afterwards.

Comment: Why not simply  `value = min(value, 5)`

Comment: @swiftPunk I added a SwiftUI example to display that `didSet` comes directly after the setter, so setting value to 5 will happen before `Text` updates.

Please let me know if you have any other questions, otherwise please accept my answer...

Comment: Nice logic way to slice issue to parts, you can use even another way like this to monitor the real setting value: **.onChange(of: value) { newValue in print("value:", newValue) }**

Comment: @swiftPunk yes when coding in SwiftIUI you can use `.onChange` to clamp your value